# jQuery issue: how to use setInerval function to implement a infinite loop

Tags: jquery

How to implement following function by setInterval() in jQuery?

```
function1(){
  $("#img1").show();
  $("#img02").delay(1000).show();
  $("#img03").delay(2000).show();
  $("#img04").delay(3000).show();
  $("#img01").delay(4000).hide();
  $("#img02").delay(4000).hide();
  $("#img03").delay(4000).hide();
  $("#img04").delay(4000).hide();
}
$(function(){
  setInterval("function1()", 2000);
});
```

I want to show images one by one and hide them all and do it again and again.
But the code won't do what I want, images displayed not by order. Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html) tutorial.

In it, the author speaks in terms of a game, but this could be used as a loop for anything, and it's very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they don't display in order is because the animations happen in async, meaning that it will start the animation again before it finishes it the first time. Right now you're having several of the animations overlapping eachother. You should use the callback functions to achieve this.